# ¿Como puedo mostrar los datos de la bbdd como arreglo?

Tags: php, sql, array, pdo

Estimados estoy con mi siguiente duda. Estoy trabajando con un arreglo. La primera parte es mas que nada la consulta con su respectivo array.

```
include "db.php";

$sentencia =("SELECT  UPPER (MONTHNAME(fecha)) AS FECHA,SUM(cantidad) AS TOTAL
FROM barchart 
WHERE YEAR(fecha)=YEAR(NOW()) AND tipo='AGUA'
GROUP BY MONTH(fecha),tipo");

$datos = $conn->query($sentencia)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode( array('datos1'=>$datos) );
```

Asi es como se muestran los datos.

```
{"datos1":[{"FECHA":"AUGUST","TOTAL":15000},{"FECHA":"SEPTEMBER","TOTAL":42000}]}
```

La idea es que me muestre asi los datos. Alguna idea como puedo arreglar mis datos para mostrar.

```
$datos1 = array(
    array("label"=> "AUGUST", "y"=> 15000),
    array("label"=> "SEPTEMBER", "y"=> 14000)
);
```

Codigo del ejemplo que estoy ocupando. Pero no me muestra el gráfico. Estoy tratando de arreglarlo, pero tengo que tener algún error que no logro divisar aun.

El error creo que proviene de la consulta al momento de querer visualizar el gráfico

```
<?php

include "db.php";

$sentencia =("SELECT  UPPER (MONTHNAME(fecha)) AS FECHA,SUM(cantidad) AS TOTAL
FROM barchart 
WHERE YEAR(fecha)=YEAR(NOW()) AND tipo='AGUA'
GROUP BY MONTH(fecha),tipo");

$datos = $conn->query($sentencia)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r(array('datos1'=>$datos));

?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>  
<script>
window.onload = function () {
 
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  animationEnabled: true,
  theme: "light2",
  title:{
    text: "Average Amount Spent on Real and Artificial X-Mas Trees in U.S."
  },
  axisY:{
    includeZero: true
  },
  legend:{
    cursor: "pointer",
    verticalAlign: "center",
    horizontalAlign: "right",
    itemclick: toggleDataSeries
  },
  data: [{
    type: "column",
    name: "Real Trees",
    indexLabel: "{y}",
    yValueFormatString: "$#0.##",
    showInLegend: true,
    dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($datos1); ?>
  },{
    type: "column",
    name: "Artificial Trees",
    indexLabel: "{y}",
    yValueFormatString: "$#0.##",
    showInLegend: true,
    dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($datos1); ?>
  }]
});
chart.render();
 
function toggleDataSeries(e){
  if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
  }
  else{
    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
  }
  chart.render();
}
 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 1200px;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Agradeceria mucho si me pueden ayudar.

Comment: Intenta quitarle el json_encode(), dejalo como: echo array('datos1'=>$datos);

Comment: Ojalá esta vez no borres la pregunta.

Comment: @MateoGuio adjunte el codigo. Pero aun no logro visualizar los gráficos

Comment: @Alfabravo estaba mal hecha la pregunta estimado. Por eso borre la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Creo que estás aplicando dos veces `json_encode` y eso te está dañando los datos, prueba a quitarlo al retornar los datos, poniéndolo sólo así: `echo array('datos1'=>$datos);` Supongo que ya verificaste que tu consulta no viene vacía ¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro estuve probando en local y simplemente debes cambiar la ultima linea de tu codigo. Cambia el echo por un print_r() y quitale el json encode de la siguiente manera:

Documentacion: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php

```
include "db.php";

$sentencia =("SELECT  UPPER (MONTHNAME(fecha)) AS FECHA,SUM(cantidad) AS TOTAL
FROM barchart 
WHERE YEAR(fecha)=YEAR(NOW()) AND tipo='AGUA'
GROUP BY MONTH(fecha),tipo");

$datos = $conn->query($sentencia)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//Aqui cambie el echo y le quite el json encode
print_r(array('datos1'=>$datos));
```

Comment: ahora agregue el codigo donde ocupo el array pero no me muestra el gráfico :(

Comment: Pudiste resolverlo ?

Comment: Guido estoy casi listo. Gracias por la orientación

Comment: Que hace el print_r() ? puede dejar algun link a la documentacion ?

Comment: Claro bro, https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php